# Installing pymssql in Centos 6.6 64-bit

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, pymssql

I'm trying to pip install pymssql in my Centos 6.6, but kept on experiencing this error:

> _mssql.c:314:22: error: sqlfront.h: No such file or directory
>   cpp_helpers.h:34:19: error: sybdb.h: No such file or directory

I already installed freetds, freetds-devel, and cython.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you need to install something like  python-mssql?

Comment: no python-mssql when I do yum list...thanks for the comment though

Comment: yes just saw it is obsolete replaced by pymssql, sybdb.h is included in the freetds-devel package , can you see the header files in /usr/include?

Comment: also do you have the python2 development headers installed?

Comment: yes. it's under /usr/include/freetds

Comment: and python-devel is installed?

Comment: yeah. but it's for the built-in python2.6. So what I did is get the RPM package for 2.7 using  wget ftp://195.220.108.108/linux/sourceforge/b/bu/buluoos/5.0/x86_64/gnome/rpm/main/xorg/Python-devel-2.7.6-1.1.buluoos5.0.x86_64.rpm, and install by using rpm -ivh... Still error occurs

Comment: not sure it matters but what python version does pip point to and can you add the full traceback ?

Comment: here you go http://pastebin.com/hefJimD2

Comment: You seem to have `include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include']` which does not contain the headers so that may well be the issue

Comment: alright. is there a way for setup.py to use /usr/include as include_dirs? instead of /usr/local/lib?

Comment: You could download the source and change the line in setup.py or simply try copy the items into usr/ocal/include

Comment: copying the entire freetds directory did the trick. Thanks a lot! Can you kindly place this as a reply so that I can check as the answer? thanks again

Comment: ,sure,  when I get back on my laptop I will add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the full traceback we see that `include_dirs` includes `/usr/local/include` but the header files are in `/usr/include` which I imagine has to do with the fact python 2.7 is not the system python.

You can change the `setup.py` script to include  `/usr/include` or copy the files into `/usr/local/include`