# Error while install pymssql in centos 7

Tags: python, linux, pip, pymssql, centos7

I have faced the issue while installing the pymssql in my virtual machine (Centos 7)

I had python installed version 2.7.6

Command used to install pymssql ,

```
pip intall pymssql
```

Error information;

```
[root@dpitstsvr013 magendran]# pip install pymssql
Downloading/unpacking pymssql
  Downloading pymssql-2.1.1.tar.gz (2.4MB): 2.4MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/pymssql/setup.py) egg_info for package pymssql
    setup.py: platform.system() => 'Linux'
    setup.py: platform.architecture() => ('64bit', 'ELF')
    setup.py: platform.linux_distribution() => ('CentOS Linux', '7.0.1406', 'Core')
    setup.py: platform.libc_ver() => ('glibc', '2.2.5')
    setup.py: Not using bundled FreeTDS
    setup.py: include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include']
    setup.py: library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']

    Installed /tmp/pip_build_root/pymssql/setuptools_git-1.1-py2.7.egg

Installing collected packages: pymssql
  Running setup.py install for pymssql
    setup.py: platform.system() => 'Linux'
    setup.py: platform.architecture() => ('64bit', 'ELF')
    setup.py: platform.linux_distribution() => ('CentOS Linux', '7.0.1406', 'Core')
    setup.py: platform.libc_ver() => ('glibc', '2.2.5')
    setup.py: Not using bundled FreeTDS
    setup.py: include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include']
    setup.py: library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    building '_mssql' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mssql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mssql.o -DMSDBLIB
    _mssql.c:314:22: fatal error: sqlfront.h: No such file or directory
     #include "sqlfront.h"
                          ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/pymssql/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-t3ztti-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    setup.py: platform.system() => 'Linux'

setup.py: platform.architecture() => ('64bit', 'ELF')

setup.py: platform.linux_distribution() => ('CentOS Linux', '7.0.1406', 'Core')

setup.py: platform.libc_ver() => ('glibc', '2.2.5')

setup.py: Not using bundled FreeTDS

setup.py: include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include']

setup.py: library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']

running install

running build

running build_ext

building '_mssql' extension

creating build

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mssql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mssql.o -DMSDBLIB

_mssql.c:314:22: fatal error: sqlfront.h: No such file or directory

 #include "sqlfront.h"

                      ^

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/pymssql/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-t3ztti-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/pymssql
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
[root@dpitstsvr013 magendran]#
```

Can you please provide some solution if you have or else it would be helpful if you could give other way to install pymssql in centos7

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28343666/installing-pymssql-in-centos-6-6-64-bit

Answer (score 9):

You need to install freetds-devel (yum install freetds-devel), most likely available in EPEL.

Answer (score 5):

File sqlfront.h is provided by freetds-devel. Ensure this is installed

```
yum install freetds-devel
```

Now... verify that the file exists. For CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503, this was here:

```
ls -l /usr/include/sqlfront.h
```

Once found, set C_INCLUDE_PATH so pip / gcc can locate it:

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include
```

now re-run pip...